# iOS Development: Should the "playersToInvite" property contain an array of strings or an array of GKPlayer objects?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, gamekit, game-center

Should the `playersToInvite` property of the `GKMatchRequest` object contain an array of NSString objects that hold the player id's or should it contain an array of GKPlayer objects?  The documentation on this critical property is not clear at all and I've tried both ways, but my code isn't working, so I can't tell by experimentation.

Here's the description for that property in the docs...

> A list of players to invite to the
>   match.

Why did they even bother writing that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is answered with the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW19) when it states:

> The playersToInvite parameter is
>   non-nil when your application is
>   launched directly from the Game Center
>   application to host a match. **This
>   parameter holds an array of player
>   identifiers for the players to invite
>   to the game**

Have to agree with you regarding the GKMatchRequest docs - that's quite uncharacteristically poor of Apple.

Comment: thanks, middaparka, i looked through the game kit guide and must have missed it, thank you!